# JobRunr not triggering the jobs after db connection lost and restarted again

Tags: java, spring-boot, jobrunr

I am using Jobrunr(4.0.1) free version. we have upgraded our postgres database so it went down for some time and after this jobrunr stop working. Now i have schedule a corn job and checking if BackgroundJobServer is running or not. if not then i am restarting again.

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0/180 * * ? * *")
@SchedulerLock(
        name = "job_lock",
        lockAtLeastFor = "30s",
        lockAtMostFor = "40s"
)
@Trace(dispatcher=true)
public void restartJobs(){
    log.error("in Job Runner");
    if(JobRunr.getBackgroundJobServer() != null && !JobRunr.getBackgroundJobServer().isRunning()) {
        JobRunr.getBackgroundJobServer().start();
    }
```

it successfully restarted but now it's not triggering the jobs.

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.jobrunr</groupId>
            <artifactId>jobrunr</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

I also identified this issue and raised a bug: https://github.com/jobrunr/jobrunr/issues/473, which is solved with version 5.1.4 .

Hope this helps.